# How can I read the value inside a TextInput?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a TextInput, and have a function named onEnterPin.

But i just couldnt reach that value. All I want is to get the value inside TextInput, and navigate to another screen if the value inside TextInput is correct

Could you help me? Btw one more question: After the pin is correct, i navigate to Home screen, and on Home screen I should have rooms(like living room etc, and items(tv, internet etc) under the room name and picture. Could you give me hint?

Here is the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet, TextInput, Alert } from "react-native";



const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

const [pin, setPin] = useState('');
  
  const CORRECT_PIN = "5555";
  const onEnterPin = (pin)=>{
      if(pin === CORRECT_PIN) {
      
        navigation.navigate("Home");
      }
      else{
        Alert.alert("problem here")
      }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Welcome to Rooms Page</Text>
      <Button 
        title="Go to HomeScreen"
        onPress = {() => {
          navigation.navigate("Home", {
            itemId: 86,
            otherParam: "anything you want here"
          });
        }} // go to the screen named Home
      />
      <Text>PIN gir</Text>
      <TextInput value={pin} style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={pin => setPin(pin)}></TextInput>
      <Button
         title="Enter"
         onPress = {() => {
           onEnterPin(value); // i guess the problem is here, what should i write
         }}
      />
      
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#307ecc',
  },
  textInput: {
    borderWidth:.5,
    height:35,
    margin:12,
    
    
  }
});


export default SplashScreen;

HomeScreen.js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";


const HomeScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { itemId } = route.params;
  const { otherParam } = route.params;

  

  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
      <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
      <Button 
        title="Go back"
        onPress = {() => navigation.goBack()}
      />
      <Button 
        title="go to example screen"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Example")}
      />
      <Button 
        title="go to Home page again, using push"
        onPress = {() => { 
          navigation.push("Home", {
            itemId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
          }),
          navigation.setParams({itemId:200}) // it updates itemId as 200, then does random number job in Math.random()
        }}
      />
    </View>
// Avoid using setParams to update screen options such as title etc. If you need to update options, use setOptions instead.
  )
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: ```const onEnterPin = ()=``` remove the parameter like this and check this should work

Comment: gives me an error as "undefined is not an object(evaluating route.params.itemId)  i added HomeScreen.js too in case you would want to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change onEnterPin parameter from **value** to **pin** like this:

```
<Button
     title="Enter"
     onPress = {() => {
      onEnterPin(pin); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      }}
 />
```

Comment: gives me an error as "undefined is not an object(evaluating route.params.itemId) i added HomeScreen.js too in case you would want to look at

Comment: Here a working snack https://snack.expo.io/@malfuckingfurion/5b84d0 . Maybe will help you

Comment: But it goes to Home screen only by clicking on button. I just want it to go to Home screen if the text is 5555, for example.

Comment: it still gives me error saying about route.params.itemId, itemId is something i just used as an example tho, its not related to this function

Comment: Sorry forgot to put if/else statement. Just fix the snack

Comment: thank you, but why my code doesnt run. Whats different? I didnt add  itemId : pin, but it shouldnt be the reason i guess

Comment: Check function App() in the snack .You need too add initialParams for itemId.

Comment: I didnt know I have to use something like this(initial params, item id), for doing this

Answer (score 0):

my Textinput has an ID and with this we can do this:

```
document.getElementById(id).value
```

to get the value of the Input.

Comment: but this is like javascript itself, i mean i want to do it as react, react-native

Comment: Why using vanilla when using react ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass it to a function since the `pin` value already exists in local state:

```
const onEnterPin = () => {
  if (pin === CORRECT_PIN) {
    navigation.navigate("Home");
  }
  else {
    Alert.alert("problem here")
  }
};
```

and:

```
<TextInput value={pin} style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={setPin} />
<Button
  title="Enter"
  onPress={onEnterPin}
/>
```

Comment: thank you. But it gave me an error  "undefined is not an object(evaluating route.params.itemId) i added HomeScreen.js too , you might want to look at. 
it was working before i add this onEnterPin function

Answer (score 0):

As the 'pin' variable exists as a local state, you can use it in the 'onEnterPin()' method, without using a parameter.

The 'onEnterPin' method will be as:

```
 const onEnterPin = () => {
  if(pin === CORRECT_PIN) {
    navigation.navigate("Home")
  }
  else{
    Alert.alert("problem here")
  }
 }
```